# i would like to make a particle effect for all players in creative mode

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

im trying to get particles to show on all players in game mode creative. Currently i have this command:

```
/execute at <player> run particle minecraft:enchant ~ ~ ~ 1 1 1 1 10 force
```

How do i make this effect ONLY gamemode creative ???
thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is the syntax for `/particle`:

```
/particle <name> <pos> <delta> <speed> <count> [force|normal] [viewers]
```

In your case you didn't specify the viewers, so it defaults to `@a`. To make the particles only visible to players in creative mode you can use this command:

```
/execute at @a run particle minecraft:enchant ~ ~ ~ 1 1 1 1 10 force @a[gamemode=creative]
```

If you want the particles to be visible to everyone, but only be around players in creative mode, then you can use this command:

```
/execute at @a[gamemode=creative] run particle minecraft:enchant ~ ~ ~ 1 1 1 1 10 force
```